# Combobox store loaded but won't display

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

I want to update the combobox store whenever there is a change in the combobox and display this changed store. My store is loading but combobox won't display it. I can display local store like I want to display but can't do the same for remote json store.

I have a "ProcessController" like this:

```
onComboboxChange: function(combo, newValue, oldValue) {
    var upContainer = combo.up('container');

    if(combo.itemId == "cmbServiceList") {
        MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore = this.createServiceCmbStore(upContainer.getComponent('cmbServiceList').getRawValue());
    }
},

createServiceCmbStore: function(inputData){
    var data = {"inputData": inputData};

    var mainController =  MyApp.app.getController('MainController');
    var cmbServiceData = mainController.callService(data,'getServices','json');
    var classServices = Ext.JSON.decode(cmbServiceData);

    var projectStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['key', 'text'],
        data: classServices
    });
    return projectStore;
}

init: function(application) {
    this.control({
        'combobox': {
            change: this.onComboboxChange
        }
    });
    _myAppGlobal = this;
},
```

And it's my combobox in the main viewport:

```
{
    xtype : 'combobox',
    anchor : '80%',
    listConfig : {
        loadingText : 'Searching...',
        emptyText : 'No matching posts found.'
    },
    typeAhead : true,
    itemId : 'cmbServiceList',
    fieldLabel : 'Servis Adı:',
    hideTrigger : true,
    displayField : 'text',
    store : MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore,
    valueField : 'key',
    minChars : 1,
    queryMode : 'local',
    forceSelection: true
}
```

`MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore` is a global variable defined in the `app.js`

When I debug the code I can see the store is loaded but it won't display any stored value in the combobox.

Comment: if(combo.itemId == "cmbServiceList") {
      MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore = this.createServiceCmbStore(upContainer.getComponent('cmbServiceList').getRawValue());
            upContainer.getComponent('cmbServiceList').bindStore(MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore);
     }

instead of

    if(combo.itemId == "cmbServiceList") {
        MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore = this.createServiceCmbStore(upContainer.getComponent('cmbServiceList').getRawValue());
    }

solved the issue.

Comment: post it as an answer :) it's unreadable and it is in fact an answer, maybe it can help others with similar issues

Comment: Sorry I tried that, but the site says "You can't answer your own question in 8 hours"

Answer (score 0):

The issue mainly here is, when your combobox is created the MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore is null or undefined, once the combobox is initialized and then you try to define your store it doesn't the combobox as the reference given during initialization to combobox was undefined.

Based on your code it seems that you are just changing the data of the store and not the store fields. So its much better you create the store before combobox initialization and then on combox change you just add the data to store by using store.add

I would recommend another approach, that is add a proxy to your store for the service and just do store.load() on combo change

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but at the start i defined MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore as null then when there is a change i changed the store with given value. Store loaded as I can see on the debug but combobox couldn't display that store.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(combo.itemId == "cmbServiceList") {
        MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore = this.createServiceCmbStore(upContainer.getComponent('cmbServiceList').getRawValue());
        upContainer.getComponent('cmbServiceList').bindStore(MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore);
    }
```

instead of

```
if(combo.itemId == "cmbServiceList") {
    MyApp.app.globals.cmbServiceStore = this.createServiceCmbStore(upContainer.getComponent('cmbServiceList').getRawValue());
}
```

solved the issue.